# How do I preview an image via a presigned S3 URL in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS presigned download URL with a 20 second expiration:

```
https://our-namespace.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/7443912/ffb9bbc5-5f4f-4315-a4e8-418bc31dbef2.png?X-Amz-Security-Token=123&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211007T004004Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=20&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA4SLAKW7L216GHWOI%2F20278006%2Fus-east-1%2GF3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=123
```

When I load this URL in the browser, it forces a download. I'm looking for a way to display this as an image preview within the browser - instead of initiating a file download.

My initial thought was to convert this URL into a blob and then display that blob in an image preview modal. The only issue is, I'm unsure how to do that. I found the following package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob` but it looks like this is no longer maintained.

What would be the optimal way of displaying an image as a preview from the AWS download only link?

Comment: Is the correct content-type set for the underlying S3 object? What does your browser do for other PDFs?

Comment: The response headers from AWS are the issue. AWS sends the "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", but you need "Content-Type: application/pdf"

Comment: @jarmod @Unigazer I accidentally used the wrong url format for the S3 link. I just updated it in the question - do your comments still apply? If so, how can I make AWS send the `content-type` as `application/pdf`? And how do you know it's coming in as `application/octet-stream`? I'm unsure how to view this

Comment: Yes, the content type matters. This dictates how the downloaded file is presented to the user agent. All SDKs and the awscli allow the uploader to indicate the content type.

Comment: @jarmod Gotcha, but how do you know it's currently `application/octet-stream` by just seeing the url?

Comment: I didn't say it was that, but that's the default for a stream of bytes with no explicit content type.

Comment: So if the `content-type` header is `application/octet-stream` it will automatically cause the browser to initiate a download, where as if the `content-type` is `application/pdf` then it will just preview it in the browser - is that correct? I wouldn't be able to set the header to `application/pdf` because sometimes they are images. How would i get around that issue?

Comment: @Noob you just need to set the content-type to `image/png` before you output the downloaded image. Or even better, install some library that returns the appropriate content-type based on the file extension. Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: @darklightcode the issue is the file could be a pdf, jpg or png. I currently don't have code because I'm trying to solve the initial problem of previewing the image in the browser instead of automatically downloading it.

Comment: @Noob it has an extension in the URL, it's png. If you want more you can install a package that detects the mimetype from the file contents.

Comment: Set the most appropriate content type on the object stored in S3. It doesn't matter that you need to support multiple types (PDF, JPEG, PNG etc.) for multiple objects. Each has *one* content type.

Comment: @darklightcode my bad - i should've mentioned that this was just an example. The url could have pdf, jpeg or pdf as the file-extension. It varies based on the file. What would I set the `content-type` header to in this case?

Comment: @Noob can't you make public the bucket ? Or even better, create a subdomain with a proxy that contains the AWS key and that rewrites the url path

Comment: @jarmod So if I set a content-type header to image/png and the file is actually pdf or jpeg, then it will still work as expected?

Comment: @darklightcode Sadly not, it's a private bucket with confidential information. I don't have access to any of the bucket properties since devops handles that and takes in requests to change headers, etc. However, after following the link it looks like the `content-type` header is `binary/octet-stream` @jarmod

Comment: @Noob that's fine, create a middleware to act like a proxy. You need to show us some code.

Comment: All of this talk of proxies and coding solutions shouldn't be necessary. S3 objects can have Content-Type metadata. Go set this correctly on an uploaded PNG and on a PDF, then generate pre-signed URLs for each, then invoke those URLs in your browser. Your browser can then choose to display/preview the file rather than download it. Note: if you upload files through the AWS S3 Console, it will typically assign the correct Content-Type, so you don't have to.

Comment: @darklightcode your earlier suggestions appear to be assuming that the OP himself is serving up the file and can therefore manipulate the content type header. That's not what's happening here. The file is being served from S3.

Comment: What @jarmod said - you just need to set the `Content-Type` like the rest of the world does when serving files to determine the file type; no need for any code or middleware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the correct [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) for each object in S3, for example `application/pdf` or `image/png`.

You can do this when uploading the object, or you can use the AWS S3 Console to modify it afterwards. Note that `Content-Type` is considered metadata.

Setting the correct `Content-Type` on the object means that when the object is served by S3 or CloudFront, that Content-Type will be conveyed to the client, allowing it to decide to display or download, as appropriate.

Comment: Gotcha, so currently the `content-type` header is always `binary/octet-stream`. Just to make sure I understand you correctly - if I have the header changed to something more appropriate, like `image/png`, then I'll be able to preview this in an image tag like `<img src="s3-link-with-correct-headers" />`?

Comment: Yes, browser and other potential caching issues notwithstanding. This should be simple to confirm (as suggested earlier). Upload a couple of PDFs or PNGs, one with the correct content type, one without. Create pre-signed URLs for each, then paste them into your browser URL bar (or use them in a simple HTML file as img src attributes).